# SQL Server query to get count value each day

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to count the number of event in each day between given time period. This is what I have tried, but it counts total events in given period. I need to count each day amount. Is this something possible to do in one query? For ex: 2016-01-01->2 , 2016-01-02->1 etc.

```
SELECT count(ID)as events 
FROM table 
WHERE VehicleName='testvehicle' 
    AND DueDate IS NOT NULL 
    AND DueDate >= '2016-01-01' 
    AND DueDate <= '2016-12-31'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: group by convert(date, DueDate)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just need a `group by`:

```
SELECT DueDate, count(ID) as events
FROM table
WHERE VehicleName = 'testvehicle' AND
      DueDate >= '2016-01-01' AND DueDate <= '2016-12-31' 
GROUP BY DueDate;
```

Note:  The expression `DueDate IS NOT NULL` is redundant.  The comparisons will fail if `DueDate` is NULL`.